# output file to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to parse a data from json file and create csv file from that output. I've written the python script to create output as per my needs. I need to sort the below csv file in time and date.

current output

[image: current output]

My code:

```
## Shift Start | End time. | Primary | Secondary
def write_CSV () :
    # field names
    fields = ['ShiftStart', 'EndTime', 'Primary', 'Secondary']
    # name of csv file
    filename = "CallingLog.csv"

    # writing to csv file
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
        # creating a csv dict writer object
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames = fields)
        # writing headers (field names)
        writer.writeheader()
        # writing data rows
        writer.writerows(totalData)
```

I want my csv file to be sorted out with date and time like below. atleast date would be fine.

```
ShiftStart                           
2020-11-30T17:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-01T01:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-02T05:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-03T05:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-04T09:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-05T13:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-06T13:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-07T09:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-08T17:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-09T09:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-10T09:00:00-08:00       
2020-12-11T17:00:00-08:00
```

Comment: sort `totalData` before you pass it to `writerows`

Comment: I have tried few suggestions in stackoverflow. but somehow it is failing to do. what exactly i should? @rdas

Answer (score 0):

```
YourDataframe.sort_values(['Col1','Col2']).to_csv('Path')
```

Try this, this not only sort and copy to csv but also retain original dataframe without sorting in program for further operations if needed..!

Comment: Thanks @Brainiac, which line i have to add this. could you please be more specific. I'm newbie to python. it will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this example to your data (that I have not in my possession -:)

```py
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
from sys import stdout

# simple, self-contained data
data = '''\
a,b,c
3,2,1
2,2,3
1,3,2
'''.splitlines()

# read the data
dr = DictReader(data)
rows = [row for row in dr]

# print the data

print('# unsorted')
dw = DictWriter(stdout, dr.fieldnames)
dw.writeheader()
dw.writerows(rows)

print('# sorted')
dw = DictWriter(stdout, dr.fieldnames)
dw.writeheader()
dw.writerows(sorted(rows, key=lambda d:d['a']))
# unsorted
a,b,c
3,2,1
2,2,3
1,3,2
# sorted
a,b,c
1,3,2
2,2,3
3,2,1

In [40]:
```

When you read the data using a `DictReader`, each element of the list `rows` is a dictionary, keyed on the field names of the first line of the CSV data file.

When you want to sort this list according to the values corresponding to a key, you have to provide `sorted` with a `key` argument, that is a function that returns the value on which you want to sort.

This function is called with the whole element to be sorted, in your case a dictionary, and we want to sort on the first field of the CSV, the one indexed by `'a'`, so that our function, using the lambda syntx to inline the definition in the function call, is just `lambda d: d['a']` that returns the value on which we want to sort.

NOTE the sort in this case is alphabetically sorted, and works because I'm dealing with single digits, in general you possibly need to convert the value (by default a string) to something else that makes sense in your context, e.g., `lambda d: int(d['a'])`.

Comment: I have completed my answer with an explanation and an _important_ note.  In your case it depends, if the date is in ISO format you can just use the lexicographical order, otherwise you have to convert…

Comment: what is that 'd' represents. in my case a == shiftstart. ?

Comment: @Sreeman _" == shiftstart ?"_? However.  We are sorting `rows`,  a list of dicts, using an _ad hoc_ function, defined on the spot using lambda syntax. OK? This function is applied to _each element_ of  `rows` (i.e., a dict) and the sort is done on the results of these function evaluations. OK? The function necessarily must use a name to refer to the element on which it operates, and this name is chosen by the person who defines the function, in our case by me… I decided that, because the function works on a dict (the elements of `rows` are dicts) the name would be `d` as in `d`ictionary.